# UIButton not recognising tap when returning to view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, ios10

I am having a issue which I have searched everywhere to try and find the answer for a while now.

I have 5 view controllers which go in the same order throughout. The first view is a UIView with and UIImage and UIButton. When loading the app the button works and you can take the photo and the rest of the app works as expected. If I go back (using the navigation controller back button) or get to the final view controller and use

```
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

I cannot tap the button, it does not recognise my tap. I am thinking it could be to do with the button being under the view but I have tried setting the button as a subview of my view but this does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks all.

Ed

Comment: Are you doing anything in code besides `popToRoot`? Are you assigning the tap function via @IBAction from storyboard, or via code?

Comment: Try the Debug View Hierarchy button in Xcode to see if there's something on top of your button. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html

Comment: Is it that there is a view on top of the button? If so you need to set its `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `false`.

Comment: a bit more code might be helpful to help you.. there might be tens of side effects from the rest of the code that can cause this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone!! Simple solution of disabling user interaction on my camera view solved it. I'm not 100% sure what the difference is from the view controller being built the first time and loading it again when going back but will figure that out. Thanks again!